# Div go down automatically when user go down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a welcome message to user 
my code is

```css
#apDiv1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 650px;
    z-index: 0;
    background-image: url("http://www.all-sweets.com/gradient-wallpaper/white-gradient/white-gradient-6-1920x1080.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div id="apDiv1">
    <img src="http://www.omagdigital.com/images/articles/WebArticle-CloseButton.png" alt="" />
    <center>
        <font color="red">
            <h2>Hi Friends Like US</h2>
        </font>
        <h3>Don't Forget To Join With
            <br />
            Our Community
            <br />
            You can like our Facebook Page by Simply Press Like Button.
            <br />
            After that close this box by clicking Close Button.
            <br />
            Thank You
        </h3>
    </center>
</div>
```

my problem is when user go down the div stay in same place
i want to when user go down the div also go down 
how can i do that?

Comment: cahnge `position:absolute;` to `position:fixed;`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/q0cdqcfy/1/ No issue at all

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the position css instead of `position:absolute;` use `position:fixed;`

Answer (score -1):

Shan, I think you are just missing one simple thing. You have `position` set to `absolute`, when it should be `fixed`. Setting it to fixed will allow that `<div>` follow you when you scroll. Here is how your finished code should appear:

```
#apDiv1 {
    position: fixed;  //just right here ;)
    left: 40px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 650px;
    z-index: 0;
    background-image: url("http://www.all-sweets.com/gradient-wallpaper/white-gradient/white-gradient-6-1920x1080.jpg");
}
```